# Are there any more Mech Warrior dark age novels?

Tags: books, hard-sci-fi, battletech

I have read the 30 novels set in the DarkAge era. I'm just wondering if the stories have continued with another Publisher that I'm not aware of!

*To ride a chimera* was the last one I read and the writers were awesome, the backstory was awesome.

It's a shame about WizKids closing down the novels as the story arc was reaching a boiling point, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number 30 actually **approaches closer toward 100** if you include all of the pre-Darkage series novels which, if you consider that the Battletech universe had a relatively small dedicated fan base (at least in comparison to other franchises), is a great deal of literature.

However, to answer your question, I looked around a bit and it seems that the company [Catalyst Game Labs](http://www.catalystgamelabs.com/battletech/) purchased the rights to continue producing the game and publishing the books back in 2009 and had every intention of continuing story lines forward.  However, after prodding about the announcements and product sections I couldn't find any new announcements regarding new fiction novels, only rules supplements for the game.  After combing through the site for a bit I finally made my way through to the official forums to the following [relevant thread](http://bg.battletech.com/forums/index.php/topic,23021.0.html) which, if the collective cries of anguish are any clue, there seems to be no new novels planned anytime soon.  This would definitely seem to be the case as the last official fiction to be published that was set in the Battletech universe, *"Shadows of Faith"*, was done back in 2010 and wasn't even a complete work before Catalyst pulled the plug and only put forward the first few chapters.  The source for that last bit, as well as a full book list of all available novels can be [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BattleTech_novels#MechWarrior%3a_Dark_Age_novels).

Sorry to be a wet blanket but it looks like for the time being, you're going to either have to go back to the older books, reread the Darkage novels, or settle for the large amount of [fan-fiction](http://bg.battletech.com/forums/index.php/board,50.0.html) that can be found within the forums.  **Hope this helped and good luck!**

Comment: ty for that. yea i do wnow of the older fiction, read some of them and they just couldnt catch me in the same way as the dark age novels.

Comment: Catalyst is finaly releasing their gamme Battletech in may of this year. PGI is making Merceneries 5 soonish so maybe with all the hype and all the buzz some books will be written. FINGERS crossed!

Answer (score 1):

BattleTech: A Bonfire of Worlds is the last "official" MechWarrior/Dark Age book that I know of.  It would be #31 in the series, and is only available as an e-boook.  You can find it on Amazon.